# How to redirect to an external url outside the react router dom management

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Hi need to redirect to an external url after a logout made by a specific profile saved in the env profiles of my react application.

example:
baseUrl --> [www.mywebsite.com](http://www.mywebsite.com), so every link in my router dom continues from the base mywebsite/

The problem is, I need to redirect to lets say, [www.google.com](http://www.google.com), but using useNavigate of react router dom or using basic js like window.location.replace always redirect me to www.mywebsite/google.com when I just want only [www.google.com](http://www.google.com)
How can I force it?

Comment: The react-router can use only for internal links. If you want to route to external links then the javascript way will work. `window.location.href = "https://www.google.com/"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use window.location.href = "https://www.google.com/" with full url not just "www.google.com" or something other